# What Framework To Use for Asynchronous Algorithms?

Tags: algorithms

I have a problem with an extremely large dataset (who doesn't?) which is stored in chunks such that there is low variance across chunks (i.e., the chunks are *sort of* representative). I wanted to play around with algorithms to do some classification in an asynchronous fashion but I wanted to code it up myself.

A sample code would look like

```
start a master
distribute 10 chunks on 10 slaves
while some criterion is not met 
 for each s in slave:
  classify the data inexactly using some kind of iterative algorithm and return to master
 master waits for any 2 slaves to report the classifier, averages the classifier and sends it back for the slaves to continue
```

What framework do I use? Hadoop, Spark, Other?

If I was doing this in pure-C, I would use pthreads and have a very fine control over threads, locks and mutexes. Is there any analogous framework in this distributed data-science environment?

Answer (score 0):

Spark is one of the most established distributed computing frameworks. Spark has MLlib, a library for machine learning, which includes many [classification algorithms](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-classification-regression.html).